# How do I get information from a form using webapp2?

Tags: python, html, webapp2

I have the following scenario:

```
<form class=*** method="post" action=("main.py" ???)>
<input class=*** type="email" name="email">
<input class=*** type="submit" value=***>
</form>
```

This form is in a .html file, evidently in a different file from the python code. I wish know which ways do I have to get the information from the form and send to the python file to finally work on it (I guess is something about the action field but not sure).

OBS: I must use the webapp2 (I'm using the google server so django and other stuff do not work on it)

Answer (score 4):

You can see  [Handling Forms with webapp2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms) from the Google App Engine `wepapp2` tutorial.

```
import cgi
from google.appengine.api import users
import webapp2

MAIN_PAGE_HTML = """\
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="/sign" method="post">
      <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_HTML)

class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.write('<html><body>You wrote:<pre>')
        self.response.write(cgi.escape(self.request.get('content')))
        self.response.write('</pre></body></html>')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/sign', Guestbook),
], debug=True)
```

And read through the entire tutorial for more information about `Datastore` and `template`

Using `template` allow you to put code html code in another file.

Comment: That's the point: I can't use this "in line" html. The must be in separate files

Comment: See the template tutorial : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates